# plot_ly: possible to set a theme for scatter3D plotting?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I haven't been able to find how to set a theme for the scatter3d type in plotly:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggthemes)

plot_ly(x,y,z, type="scatter3d") + theme_igray()
```

It returns a NULL. Is this possible at all with plotly?

Comment: the ggthemes packages is made for ggplot not plotly. meaning you could generate a ggplot and use the theme and then convert to with plotly::ggplotly(). Though some layout feature will not be translated. Also the syntax for plotly is not "+" but the pipe operador %>% Last but not least all of this wont help you as your are looking for a 3D scatterplot. The only option I see is to use plotly::layout() and define what you want the plot to look like manually https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, an answer about it not being possible using themes :)